# SqlPackage importing of very large bacpacs to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, import, sqlpackage

I want to import a database from a `.bacpac` file to a SQL Server in Azure. I read the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-import?view=sql-server-ver15).

It says that there is a flag called `DatabaseMaximumSize=(INT32)`.

I wanted to know if there's a limit that sqlpackage can support?

For example, if I got 8 GB of RAM available, will Sqlpackage be able to load larger `.bacpac` files than that, meaning it doesn't load it all to the memory?

Answer (score 0):

Is this SQL Server on a VM or Azure SQL Database / Azure SQL Managed Instance ?
Probably one of the last 2 as you could just use a backup to restore to SQL on a VM, If you find the import runs to slow just scale up your machine until the import is completed

Comment: on managed instance. And im not talking about runtime performance, but on memory allocation. What happens if the bacpac is larger than my available ram?

Comment: I don't know but it would be an absolute first if a bacpac import can only succeed if there is more RAM than the size of the file, there seem to be adequate mechanisms to run with a database that is larger than the RAM available, so why would it be different for a BACPAC ?

Comment: there's for example the dacfx in .net core which has an import method which receives a bacpac, but the option to tell it not to load everything to the memory doesn't work there

Comment: Can you point to the documentation of that option (to not load all into memory) you mention?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the amount of **Memory** is a factor and it should be buffered if your **.BACPAC** file is larger than the amount you have available. (This is a pretty common case that your database is larger than your **Memory**.) The only thing to note in hardware limitations is if the machine used to process the **.BACPAC** is doing so via Azure Portal or Powershell, the amount of disk space available may need to be up to triple the size of the **.BACPAC** itself, as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import?tabs=azure-powershell). There are a few other limitations at the end of that document, none of which are related to hardware or **Memory**.

Comment: I agree. The data is after all BCP files in the zip file (a BACPAC is a zip file) and it would be very strange if the import routine would digest everything in memory before loading it.